# run VBA code to update dropdownlist value when excelsheet is updated

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I would like to know how can i bind values to drodownlist each time when the particular worksheet get updated by new values.

Can anyone help me to do this

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Take a look at the Worksheet_Change Event.

Comment: Also, try a dynamic named range to make things easier, so if it starts in A1, =offset(a1,0,0,counta(A:A),1) something like that, if no gaps are in the list..

Answer (score 1):

You could name the range that the values are in. Bind the dropdownlist to that named range - then when you update the sheet update the named range.

Comment: Yep, agree with Jpad. Additionally you should be able to use a formula for the drop down which dynamically resizes as you append to the list. Also as an extra alternative, you could possibly use the changed event for that sheet and update the list of items.